# Swap any token for any token - Sniper Bot Javascript - - pancakeswap, quickswap, caffeswap

Tags: javascript, bots, token, blockchain, cryptocurrency

We are making this sniper bot https://github.com/Nafidinara/bot-pancakeswap , which only can swap WBNB (or MATIC or KCS, depends on the blockchain you select) for any token.

So we want to swap any tokens for any tokens.

Example: swap CAKE for WBTC

The function that you will find at this code is "swapETHforExactTokens". Now we are using "swapExactTokensforTokens" for swapping any token, and it runs well, but we get this error at the blockchain:

TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xf584e421990628131b92b22b2aad270e91752287817eeb518a4d9bdb4b37d086

Do you know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you still looking for a solution
I believe you have not approved the token
Ex: if you are buying with Usdt , you should have approved the token first

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).